# Expo: Invariant Violation: ListView has been removed - but I don't use ListView

Tags: react-native, listview, expo

I inherited a React Native / Expo app. I upgraded the expo version. Now I get the message that ListView has been removed. I have searched 
`grep -Ri listview *` the entire codebase and ListView is not used anywhere in our codes - why am I getting this messages? If a dependency uses it somehow, how do I find out which one?

The emulator stack trace seems to not contain any of our modules, just a bunch of  and loadModuleImplementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ListView was used by some of our dependencies. There were a few mentions of it in node_modules. I think I got them all by updating every single dependency we had to the latest version.

You could update one dependency at a time, one version at a time for a minimal fix, but that would probably take very, very long as constantly running `npm install / expo install` is very slow.